# Full-calendar scheduler is not displaying with resources: It seems scheduler file is not loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using vue-full-calendar library and full calendar scheduler for displaying resources in my app. Everything worked well.The calendar shows resources and the app is running since almost two years. But the last days it is impossible to display the calendar with resources .I have everything set up and i use the same library version as the docs suggest [in this code sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/qlp8jvko3j).
After debug i notice that the scheduler plugin is not loading.I don't understand why it stop working and the library stop loading.Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong or encountered the same problem.
Thanks for your help.
EDIT:
After some checks i reinstall fullcalendar-scheduler with command : npm install --no-optional --save fullcalendar-scheduler@1.9.4  and now i've got  [this error in my  browser console](https://prnt.sc/tyucxm).

Comment: "not loading"...ok and what error do you get? e.g. did you check in the console, or the network tool in your browser?  Do you get maybe a 404 error or something like that? It's hard to help you without any specific information. You're running a very old version of fullCalendar - if you're loading the library from a CDN then maybe your CDN provider removed it from their servers or something.

Comment: Thanks @Adyson.I updated my question with console error.Right i am running an old version of full calendar but i am not loading it from a CDN but from node_modules

Comment: I'm not familiar with vue or npm so I can't help you with that aspect, it does sound a bit like some kind off odd issue with packages or something. But I've tagged the question with those technologies in case someone interested in those has got some advice for you instead.

Comment: I'm not familiar with vue or npm so I can't help you with that aspect, it does sound a bit like some kind off odd issue with packages or something. But I've tagged the question with those technologies in case someone interested in those has got some advice for you instead.